# Use the datetime string from the time tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to parse the datetime attribute to a different div.  I don't want the actual string from the time tag as this is formatted but instead want to parse the ISO date

Currently the below code spits out 01 Feb 12 but I need it to be 2012-02-01T00:00:00Z

Is it possible to do this?

```
var p = $(this);
p.attr("data-date", p.find("span.openDate time").text());

<span class="openDate"><time datetime="2012-02-01T00:00:00Z">01 Feb 12</time><span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace you code with this:

```
var p = $(this);
p.attr("data-date", p.find("span.openDate time").attr("datetime"));
```

It will now take the content from the datetime attribute

```
datetime="2012-02-01T00:00:00Z"
```

So the `data-date` would be

```
2012-02-01T00:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
p.attr("data-date", p.find("span.openDate time").attr('date-time'));
                                                  ^^^
                                                  Change here
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy27X/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = $('time').attr('datetime');
```

or

```
var x = $('span time:first-child').attr('datetime');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var dt=$('span.opentime time').attr('datetime');
$(this).attr("data-date",dt);
```